# React Native how to mock PixelRatio on 1 specific test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I am having trouble testing my snapshot in react-native, to be more specific it's the PixelRatio I am having troubles with.

Code speaks more than words - I've simplified the code and removed all the noise:

**The component:**

```
const Slide = (props) => (
  <Image
    source={props.source}
        style={PixelRatio.get() === 2 ?
            { backgroundColor: 'red' } :
            { backgroundCoor: 'green' }}
  />
);
```

**The Snapshot test**:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
describe('When loading the Slide component', () => {
  it('should render correctly on ios', () => {
    Platform.OS = 'ios';
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Slide />
      </Provider>,
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  describe('on devices with a pixelRatio of 2', () => {
    it('it should render correctly', () => {
      jest.mock('PixelRatio', () => ({
        get: () => 2,
        roundToNearestPixel: jest.fn(),
      }));

      const tree = renderer.create(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Slide />
        </Provider>,
      ).toJSON();
      expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
});
```

But this doesn't work and after some digging I found a [bug on github](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582) that was already resolved - apparently you need to use [beforeEach](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582#issuecomment-284514827). But that seems also not to be working or I am doing it wrong?

**The Snapshot test with the suggested solution of github**:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
describe('When loading the Slide component', () => {
  it('should render correctly on ios', () => {
    Platform.OS = 'ios';
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Slide />
      </Provider>,
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  describe('on devices with a pixelRatio of 2', () => {
    it('it should render correctly', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        jest.mock(pxlr, () => ({
          get: () => 2,
          roundToNearestPixel: jest.fn(),
        }));
        const pxlr = require('react-native').PixelRatio;
      }

      const tree = renderer.create(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Slide />
        </Provider>,
      ).toJSON();
      expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

When you write `jest.mock('my-module', () => {...})` you tell `jest` to mock module with the name of `'my-module'`. And then when you will write `const MyModule = require('my-module')` you'll get a mock.

So statement `jest.mock('PixelRatio', () => {...})` would make sense if `PixelRatio` was a module, but it isn't. `PixelRatio` is a global JS variable (JS `class` to be precise). You can mock its static methods as follows:

1) Using [`jest.spyOn`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) method:

```
const mockGet = jest.spyOn(PixelRatio, 'get')
  .mockImplementation(() => customImplementation)
const mockRoundToNearestPixel = jest.spyOn(PixelRatio, 'roundToNearestPixel')
  .mockImplementation(() => customImplementation)
```

2) Using [`jest.fn`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestfnimplementation) method:

```
PixelRatio.get = jest.fn(() => customImplementation)
PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel = jest.fn(() => customImplementation)
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. My test are still taking the default instead of my custom implementation.